# Cannot read property map of null

Tags: reactjs

Trying to map over some data and put it in a table, however I am not to sure why it is coming back with this error. Am I mapping over the data in correctly? I am also trying to map over and retrieve the test_type and test_dq_domain data.

ignore please:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

[image]

code:

```
const createUnitTestLandingPage = () => {

  
const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
const user = useContext(UserContext)

const [unitTestTemplates, setUnitTestTemplates] = useState(null)



useEffect(() => {
  async function getUnitTests() {
    loading.setLoading(true)
    const results = await verifiedGet(`get_unit_test_templates/0/10`, user.user)
    if(results.status === 0) {
      setUnitTestTemplates(results.data)
    } else if(results.status >=20 && results.status <=30) {
      snackbar.statusCheck(results)
      user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
    } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
    loading.setLoading(false)

  }

  getUnitTests()
}, [])



  return (



    <PageWrapper title='Create Unit Tests' instructions='Choose a test type'>

      <div className='Card' style={{marginTop: '40px'}}>
        <div className='TableTopbar CreateUnitTestsGrid'>
            <div>Test Type</div>
            <div>Typical DQ Domain</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {unitTestTemplates.map(test =>
          <div key={test.id} className='Table RegressionTestsGrid' style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
            <div>{test.test_type}</div>
            <div>{test.test_dq_domain}</div>

          </div>
        )}

    </PageWrapper>
  )
}

export default withRouter(createUnitTestLandingPage)
```

What data I am trying to map over.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since React will render the 1st time before you fetch your data, so the simple solution is either initialize with an empty Array `[]`

```
const [unitTestTemplates, setUnitTestTemplates] = useState([])
```

Or check nullable your JSX:

```
{unitTestTemplates && unitTestTemplates.map(test => ...
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks :D